# My fluid domain still visible, even after baking. The FLIP particles are clipping through the box mesh

Tags: fluid-simulation

My resolution is 200, after seeing so on another tread. [image]

Comment: On properties, press the yellow box, then go to visability, and change it to wired. Also you have to bake the mesh

Comment: @Yohello1 +1 I was wondering why Domain became to wire automatically for Gas, but Solid for Liquid. The only reason that came to my mind is - be ready when Mesh feature is enabled. But since this is almost last step in creation process I would probably appreciate automatic Wire mode also for Liquid.

Comment: @Yohello1 This way my fluid isn't visible

Comment: @leBlenderMan Have you baked the Mesh?

Answer (score 1):

Yohello1's answer in image ...

- to see inside domain go to *Properties editor > Object > Viewport Display* set **Wire**
  [image]
- or go to *Properties editor > Simulations > Fluid > Liquid* > enable **Mesh**
  [image]